# Filling class object from multiple dataset

Tags: c#, .net, linq, datatable

I want to fill the **Organism** class object with data from **OrganismDT** and **AntibioticDT**. below are the Datatable structure,Class structure and the filling technique i am trying. based on the **OrganismAliasId** i have to fill the AntibioticsDT[**Antibiotic objects list**] rows  and assign to corresponding **Organisms** object. Could any one please help me to achieve this..

### DataTable

```
DataTable OrganismDT = new DataTable("Organism");
OrganismDT.Columns.Add("OrganismAliasId");
OrganismDT.Columns.Add("Name");

DataTable AntibioticsDT = new DataTable("Antibiotics");
AntibioticsDT.Columns.Add("OrganismAliasId");
AntibioticsDT.Columns.Add("Name");
AntibioticsDT.Columns.Add("Susceptibility");
```

### Class Structure:

```
public class Organism
{
 public int AliasId { get; set; }
 public string Name { get; set; }
 public List<Antibiotic> Antibiotics;
}


public class Antibiotic
{
 public string Name { get; set; }
 public string Susceptibility { get; set; }
}
```

### filling Datatable table to Class object

```
List<Organism> Organisms = Organism.AsEnumerable().Select(row =>
new Organism
{
 AliasId = row.Field<int>("OrganismAliasId"),
 Name = row.Field<string>("Name"),
 Antibiotics = new List<Antibiotic>()
}).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:-

```
List<Organism> Organisms = OrganismDT.AsEnumerable().Select(row =>
          new Organism
          {
            AliasId = row.Field<int>("OrganismAliasId"),
            Name = row.Field<string>("Name"),
            Antibiotics = AntibioticsDT.AsEnumerable()
                        .Where(x => x.Field<int>("OrganismAliasId") 
                                       == row.Field<int>("OrganismAliasId"))
                        .Select(x => new Antibiotic
                        {
                           Name = x.Field<string>("Name"),
                           Susceptibility = x.Field<string>("Susceptibility")
                        }).ToList()
            }).ToList();
```

Also, Please note you should create the columns by specifying their datatypes otherwise it may throw run-time exception:-

```
AntibioticsDT.Columns.Add("OrganismAliasId",typeof(int));
```

Comment: It throws error saying, "column Susceptibility does not belong to the table Organism"... Organisms row data is going inside the nested select.. how to pass AntibioticsDT's row?

Comment: @Thavudu - Have you tried the exact code I have provided? As you can see we are fetching the Susceptibility column from `AntibioticsDT` only. Its working perfectly fine fro me.

Comment: I only made miskate, your code is working fine instead of x.Field i was using row.Field... Thanks for the help Rahul